# How does std::async automatically join threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semantics, stdasync

The c++ 11 `std::async` is a great thread abstraction, but every thread has to be joined so how does `std::async` join threads without exposing it to the user?

Comment: Do you know what detached threads are?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I think so. You're not supposed to join them?

Comment: `std::async` doesn't have to launch a new thread if it's called without specifying that.

Comment: Right, so what exactly is your question about `std::async` is? Shouldn't it be obvious that `std::async` simply creates a detached thread?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm creating a thread abstraction of my own, and I simply haven't been able to figure out how to join threads without making the user do it manually. I'll have to give detached threads a try!

Comment: Just a suggestion: before attempting to create a "thread abstraction of my own", it would be useful to be more familiar, and experienced, of how standard C++ library threads work, and how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::async` doesn't join threads. Instead, it initialized threads that are **detatched** from a thread object. These execution of these threads is independent of the process that created them and their resources are freed by the OS once they exit.